# Unable to get the user's name from Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Edit: I am unable to get a user's name from Firebase using the `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection.doc.get` method

My code:

```
void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedDay = selectedDay;
      _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      loadData();
    });
  }

  Future<void> loadData() async {
    final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      DocumentSnapshot userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get();

      setState(() {
        userName = (userData.data() as Map)['name'] ?? "";
      });
    }
  }
```

...

```
AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello $userName!"),
        backgroundColor: primaryColor,
      ),
```

I specifically want to get the name using the FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection.doc.get method if possible. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Suggestion: Could you share an example document stored on firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`.data()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) on the `DocumentSnapshot`:

```dart
userName = (userData.data() as Map)['name'] ?? "";
```

From [the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html):

> A DocumentSnapshot contains data read from a document in your Cloud Firestore database. The data can be extracted with `data()` or `get(<field>)` to get a specific field.

Comment: No it is still not being displayed. I tried doing this now, but its still blank in the log